# problem with the sum of user inputed values

Tags: java

i'm a java beginner and im trying to make a program that counts the calories an user has consumed throughout the day based on the food that the user has eaten, but after a certain value, the counter messes up and the program realizes an unknown operation. Here is the code:

```
package caloricintake;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaloricIntake {

   public static byte totalIntake;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean i = true;
        System.out.println("input food: ");

        do
        {

         String food = scan.next();
         if (food.equalsIgnoreCase("bread"))

            totalIntake = (byte) (totalIntake + 50);

         if (food.equalsIgnoreCase("cheese"))
          totalIntake = (byte) (totalIntake + 25);

         if (food.equalsIgnoreCase("cookie"))
          totalIntake = (byte) (totalIntake + 100);

        intake =(byte) (intake + totalIntake);
        if(food.equalsIgnoreCase("finish"))
                {
                    i = false;
                        System.out.println("Total calories:" + " " + totalIntake);         
                }
        } while (i == true);

    }

}
```

If I input "bread" two times, the program delivers 100 as expected, however if I input "bread" three times, the program delivers -106, if input "cheese" 6 times, the program also delivers -106, I have tried other combinations so far and I realised that the program messes up whenever the counter reaches 150 and I don't understand why.

Comment: Why do you use `byte` variable to count calories? It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127.

Comment: ohhh so thats the problem, damn I almost drowned in a glass of water, thanks man. Im going to write the byte value range a 100 times in the blackboard now,

Comment: @JA I'm curious: why did it come up into your mind to typecast the number to a `byte`?

Answer (score 0):

> The eight primitive data types supported by the Java programming language are: byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). [ref.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

In your case when you add multiple times to a byte; it prints the unexpected value. As a simple check, try running the following :

```
byte x = (byte)150;
System.out.println(x);   //prints -106
```

This can be further validated as you keep on inverting "bits from 1(s) to" when you explicit type cast an integer of 128 and this becomes -128 and so on.

In my opinion store an int.